# CSS - Display Text beside image (Responsive)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a container with two divs next to eachother with an image in one div and the text in another.

[image]

This is my current CSS and HTML code... however when I resize my window to view it on a web application the text moves ontop of the image, how can i make it responsive so when the user views it on their mobile the image is at the top and the text is just below:

[image]

**Display CSS:**

```
 .container{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .centerDiv
    {
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .div1
    {
        width: 45%;
        float:left;
    }
    .div2
    {
        width: 55%;
        background-color: white;
        float:left;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="centerDiv">
            <div class="div1">                
                    <img src="..." alt="..."/>
                </div>
                <div class="div2">
                    <br/>                      
                    <h6><b>LOOK AFTER ME</b></h6>
                    <h6>100% Cotton <br/>
                      <br/></h6>
                    <h6><b>STYLE GUIDE</b></h6>
                    <h6>This Tee looks just right paired<br/> with joggers, jeans or shorts. <br/>
                    </h6> <br/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please help :(

[image]

Trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use float. And make the image part of the background within the HTML.

```
<div class="item_description">
  <div class="image"
        style="background-image:url('https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB13zAXIFXXXXbxXFXXq6xXFXXX7/New-Arrival-2014-Mens-Flared-Jeans-Men-s-Bell-Bottom-Denim-Male-Big-Horn-Jean-Flare.jpg');">
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
   Description here
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS you can do something like:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
.item_description {
  width:100%;
}
.image {
  height:0;
  padding-bottom:40%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  position:relative;
  width:40%;
}
.desc, .image {
  float:left;
  display:block
}
.desc {
  width:60%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
  .desc, .image {
    float:none;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Couple of points:

- `box-sizing:border-box` is so important in responsive designs. It calculates padding as part of the total width. You can read more about that online somewhere.
- Media queries allow you to control what happens to the CSS when certain screen dimensions are met. I have added one so that at `600px` or less, the image and description stack on top of each other.

See this jsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/xnfc8vsx/3/

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `centerDiv` a width so his children can adjust.

I hope this helps. If not please add a comment so i can edit the answer.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
}

.centerDiv {
  width: 60vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div1 {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}

.div2 {
  width: 55%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

img {
width:100%;
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centerDiv">
    <div class="div1">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500" alt="..." />
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
      <br/>
      <h6><b>LOOK AFTER ME</b></h6>
      <h6>100% Cotton <br/>
        <br/></h6>
      <h6><b>STYLE GUIDE</b></h6>
      <h6>This Tee looks just right paired<br/> with joggers, jeans or shorts. <br/>
      </h6> <br/>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 Run
```

Comment: Hi @GerardoBLANCO

thank you for your reply. I've updated the code to that which you have provided. It is slighlty better as the text does not appear on top of the image... however, when resizing to mobile view the image shrinks quite alot. Is there any way I could display the image on top and then the text below? thank you for your help, I've tried many things but still can't seem to get it right. :(

Comment: I updated the question - i added two screenshots at the bottom, the first shows what I got when changing my code to that which you suggessted

the second shows what I'm trying to acheive
thanks

Comment: @AGarcia i see what you are trying to acomplish. If you could maybe include more code, i can be of more help. Also if you want i can help you with bootstrap integration, it will make your life so much easier

Comment: @AGarcia what i don understan is the first ans third image. i thought you wanted a desktop layout, but you tried my answer on a mobile layout

Answer (score -1):

For better , easy and cross browser Responsible Desgin you must check  this - 
You just have to add Corresponding class which are already defined  : Also you can get many Tutorial on internet , this one of most famous css library ✌
[Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com)

Comment: Just lnking to Bootstrap without any advise how to use bootstrap  to solve the question is not helpfull.